# Getting error while adding native transitions plugin in angular ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Trying to add native transitions to my app but getting error "Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic-native-transitions' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." I have properly added the dependency.Any lead will be appreciated.Thanks in advance :)

App.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic-native-transitions','starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function($window) {
 if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
 .config(function($stateProvider,$ionicNativeTransitionsProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {
.state('chat', {
      url: '/chat',
      nativeTransitions: {
        "type": "flip",
        "direction": "up"
    }, 
      templateUrl: 'templates/chat.html',

  })
```

HTML

```
 <div ui-sref="chat"  class="title" >
    <a  class="underline" ui-sref="chat"  native-transitions>
      <img class = "title-image" src="img/Chat@1x.png"></img>
          <p class="imgtext" style="color: rgb(102, 0, 0)">Chat</p>
    </a><br>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the dist script to your page. If you use commonjs a
simple require would do. If not include de script tag with the plugin path
in your page

```
<script src="/your/path/ionic-native-transitions.js"><script>
```